# Generating TypeScript types from Laravel backend

Tags: typescript, laravel, openapi

I'm thinking on how to generate TypeScript from my Laravel's app API. I'm using scribe to generate API documentation and then, based on it, I'm generating typescript. The problem is the message from the server, I'm generating open api docs based on Resource that the API returns, in case I want to go into this direction, each endpoint would have to have it's designated resource, and the 'server message' would be placed inside it, because otherwise the api docs won't have it.

I'm giving an example how it would look like

```
/**
 * @apiResource App\Http\Admin\Resources\PermissionCreateResource
 * @apiResourceModel App\Models\Permission
 * @param PermissionCreateRequest $request
 */
public function create(PermissionCreateRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $input = $request->validated();
    $permission = $this->permissionFactory->createPermission($input);
    return new JsonResponse(new PermissionCreateResource($permission), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

And the `PermissionCreateResource`:

```php
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'message' => 'Permission created',
        'data' => [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Regarding the good practices and the common sense, what should I do..?

Many thanks,
Cheers!

Comment: What's yours backend (Laravel+Scribe/whatever) and frontend fetch (axios/window.fetch/whatever) libraries? What's your openapi definition(`vyuldashev/laravel-openapi`) and type generators (openapi-typescript/whateber)? What DX are you targeting? Like just calling `api.get<const Path extends ApiGetPaths>(path: Path, params: ApiGetParams<>): JustData<ApiGetResult<Path>>` (i.e. `let a/*: {userId: number, name: string}*/ = await api.get('user/{userId}', {userId: 999})`) or `rpc.user.get({userId: 999})` something?

Answer (score 0):

On a personal note, I don't think I'd add a success message to the responses.
Responding with the HTTP status code 201 implies success and that something was created, in my opinion that's likely suficient.

For more specific messages such as error messages I'd likely return an error code or similar (something like "invalid-param" rather than a user-readable message), this way the frontend is responsible for formatting and presenting an error message in the user's language/locale.

Regarding the resource, I'd suggest having a `PermissionResource` that can be used for any operation made to the Permission model:

```php
public function toArray(Request $request): array
{
    return [
        'data' => [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ]
    ];
}
```

And I'd return it in any endpoint related to that model:

```php
/**
 * @apiResource App\Http\Admin\Resources\PermissionResource
 * @apiResourceModel App\Models\Permission
 * @param PermissionCreateRequest $request
 */
public function create(PermissionCreateRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $input = $request->validated();
    $permission = $this->permissionFactory->createPermission($input);
    return new JsonResponse(new PermissionResource($permission), Response::HTTP_CREATED);
}
```

Nevertheless, if you want to add endpoint-specific data to the resource, then I'd suggest passing that data into the resource from your controller, that way you can use the same resource for any endpoint related to the `Permission` model.

The laravel docs suggest calling `additional()` and passing it any meta data to be added to the resource straight from the controller.

In this case you should add the `@apiResourceAdditional` annotation to inform Scribe of the additional data.

```php
/**
 * @apiResource App\Http\Admin\Resources\PermissionResource
 * @apiResourceModel App\Models\Permission
 * @param PermissionCreateRequest $request
 * @apiResourceAdditional message="Permission created"
 */
public function create(PermissionCreateRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    $input = $request->validated();
    $permission = $this->permissionFactory->createPermission($input);
    return (new JsonResponse(new PermissionResource($permission), Response::HTTP_CREATED))
        ->additional([
            'message' => 'Permission created',
        ]);
}
```

(Source: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources#adding-meta-data-when-constructing-resources)

(Source: https://scribe.knuckles.wtf/laravel/reference/annotations#apiresourceadditional)

Hope this helps!